# WordPress not rendering HTML?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Okay I have no idea why wordpress is not rendering html, just a blank screen. Checking inspect element and I can't see the html structure of the website.

I assume the problem could be with the header however I've double checked for errors not sure. The title name on the window tab screen isn't even showing.

Any ideas: here is a link too: https://www.radian3.com

**Here is the header.php**

```
    <?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package Shape
 * @since Shape 2.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title><?php
    /*
    * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
    */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'shape' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

    <!--  This part loads a JavaScript file that enables old versions of Internet Explorer to recognize the new HTML5 elements, and it only loads for visitors who are using IE 8 or earlier. -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
     <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <hgroup>
             <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
             <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </hgroup>
         <nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">
            <!--   add a skip link so folks using a screen reader don’t have to suffer through our menu when they just want to get to the content.  -->
            <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'playTheme' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="assistive-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', '_s' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'playTheme' ); ?></a></div>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

        </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
     </header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
     <div 

id="main" class="site-main">
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Shape
 * @since Shape 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <script type="text/javascript"> alert("asdasdsa");</script>

    </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
</div><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<div>
    asldjaslkdj
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried pulling all the php out from the title bracket and seeing if the page loads then?

Comment: Are you saying delete everything in the <title> tag? have tried not working

Comment: Nothing jumps out, any new plugins?

Comment: Nope, have no clue what the problem could be! ;/

Comment: A blank screen could mean anything but it's often caused by an error in the php code (even just a syntax error). This occurs on the server before the html gets displayed, which is why you just get a blank screen (and no title, because its defined in the html). Because there's no indication of what or where the problem is, I suggest stripping out everything bit-by bit, testing each time, until it starts to work again - that will identify the code with the problem. When you find that and if you don't know why its causin a problem, come back and post it, so we can take a look!

Comment: Also: don't forget to check your sidebar and footer, even though they are at the bottom... it doesn't matter where the error occurs, it will stop anything at all from appearing. I'd also suggest disabling ALL your plugins to see if they were causing it, and if they were add them back one by one until you find the one with the problem. Debugging can be a laborious task :)

Comment: https://www.radian3.com

remove https to http

http://radian3.com/